# Trying to create reusable ASP.NET MVC application. Templates/NuGet/Both?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nuget

I have a "core" application with customized controllers and some default views that I want to use to create some custom applications that extend the core features.  I understand the process to create a template from this project.  But if I add some new core functionality I want to be able to just refresh from that template and maintain all my extensions. Templates don't seem to support this.  I've done a little experimenting with NuGet as this seems more what I want, but I'm not sure if placing an entire core application into a NuGet package is the right way to go.  Anyone done anything like this?

Comment: Ouch, why the down vote with no comment?

Answer (score 0):

> but I'm not sure if placing an entire core application into a NuGet package is the right way to go

As we know, NuGet itself is a minimal tool which requires a manifest or project file to work, and dotnet pack will only pack up the source files, and not all assets. So if you want place an entire core application into a NuGet package, you should manually add the manifest in the `.nuspec` file.

Besides, since you are only have some customized controllers and some default views that used create some custom applications, you do not need include the entire core application into a NuGet package, just add those controllers and views into the nuget package.

Since you are using core application, you should use the `ContentFiles` to include your controllers and views files. Below is my test sample:

My `.nuspec` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>MyTestCore</id>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <authors>TestContentFile</authors>
    <owners>TestContentFile</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package Description</description>
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="any/any/Views/Test.cshtml" buildAction="content" flatten="true" copyToOutput="false"/>
      <files include="any/any/Controllers/Test.cs" buildAction="content" flatten="true" copyToOutput="false"/>
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>

  <files>
    <file src="contentFiles/any/any/Views/Test.cshtml" target="contentFiles/any/any/Views/Test.cshtml" />
    <file src="contentFiles/any/any/Controllers/Test.cs" target="contentFiles/any/any/Controllers/Test.cs" />
  </files>
</package>
```

The structure of my controllers and views files in file explorer:

[image]

After pack this package and install it to other projects, controllers and views files will be add to the projects.

See [NuGet ContentFiles Demystified](https://blog.nuget.org/20160126/nuget-contentFiles-demystified.html) for more detailed info.